# How to tell without knowing the mount point that a device UUID is mounted?

Tags: mount, posix, block-device, uuid, readlink

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon 64-bit, based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

---

I would like to know if it is possible to get the following information:

**Is *this UUID* (of a block device) mounted or not? (without knowing the mount point)**

In spite, I have played along with this half a day, I can't figure it out.

I have at least created *some* working code below which un-mounts and powers off both of the USB hard drives.

---

The current, temporary, version of my code looks like this:

```sh
dismount_and_poweroff_external_drives()
{
    name_external_drive_500gb_ntfs='500GB NTFS USB 2.0 HDD'
    name_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4='2.0TB Ext4 USB 3.0 HDD'
    uuid_external_drive_500gb_ntfs='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # censored
    uuid_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' # censored
    path_external_drive_500gb_ntfs="/dev/disk/by-uuid/${uuid_external_drive_500gb_ntfs}"
    path_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4="/dev/disk/by-uuid/${uuid_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4}"

    tput bold; tput setaf 3; printf '%b' "\\n${name_external_drive_500gb_ntfs} un-mount\\n"; tput sgr0
    # info test ‘-b FILE’: True if FILE exists and is a block special device.
    if [ ! -b "${path_external_drive_500gb_ntfs}" ]
    then
        tput bold; tput setaf 4; printf '%b' "The device is not plugged in or powered on.\\n"; tput sgr0
    else
        if umount "${path_external_drive_500gb_ntfs}"
        then
            tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%b' "Un-mounting OK.\\n"; tput sgr0

            if udisksctl power-off --block-device "${path_external_drive_500gb_ntfs}"
            then
                tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%b' "Powering-off OK.\\n"; tput sgr0
            else
                tput bold; tput setaf 1; printf '%b' "Powering-off Failed.\\n"; tput sgr0
            fi

        else
            tput bold; tput setaf 1; printf '%b' "Un-mounting Failed.\\n"; tput sgr0
        fi
    fi

    printf '\n'

    tput bold; tput setaf 3; printf '%b' "\\n${name_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4} un-mount\\n"; tput sgr0
    # info test ‘-b FILE’: True if FILE exists and is a block special device.
    if [ ! -b "${path_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4}" ]
    then
        tput bold; tput setaf 4; printf '%b' "The device is not plugged in or powered on.\\n"; tput sgr0
    else
        if umount "${path_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4}"
        then
            tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%b' "Un-mounting OK.\\n"; tput sgr0

            if udisksctl power-off --block-device "${path_external_drive_2_0tb_ext4}"
            then
                tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%b' "Powering-off OK.\\n"; tput sgr0
            else
                tput bold; tput setaf 1; printf '%b' "Powering-off Failed.\\n"; tput sgr0
            fi

        else
            tput bold; tput setaf 1; printf '%b' "Un-mounting Failed.\\n"; tput sgr0
        fi
    fi

    printf '\n'
}
```

---

**I forgot to stress that the accepted solution must be [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-ly written.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Original Solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/509692/1)

```sh
UUID=<device_uuid>
mount | egrep $(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/${UUID}) && echo mounted
```

---

### [Vlastimil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/126755/vlastimil)'s Notes

- It might be a good idea to use `-e` instead of `-f`, from `readlink` help:

  > ```sh
  > -e, --canonicalize-existing   canonicalize by following every symlink in
  >                               every component of the given name recursively,
  >                               all components must exist
  > ```

  As compared to:

  > ```sh
  > -f, --canonicalize            canonicalize by following every symlink in
  >                               every component of the given name recursively;
  >                               all but the last component must exist
  > ```

  As far as I understand it, **with `-e` there is a guarantee** that the whole path exists, might be better, needs additional verification or citation. **Unfortunately, the `-e` option has been found not to be [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant, so out of luck there.** Leaving all the information here for future reference.
- There are no double quotes in the [original solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/509692/1), I'd recommend adding them along with **one trailing space as a security measure** to avoid matching e.g. `sda11` or similarly.
- One could also take advantage of [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-defined **[`fgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep) to match for a fixed string**, or even better match only line starting with this device using `grep "^dev_name"`.
- As has been pointed out by [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick), `mount` itself may not be [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-defined, again, a citation would be handy, but anyway I've changed the code to read from `/proc/mounts` directly.

---

### Plausible function

The **resulting function** for checking if UUID is mounted **could** look similar to:

```sh
is_uuid_mounted()
{
    readlink_output=$( readlink -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/"${1}" )
    [ -n "${readlink_output}" ] &&
        grep -F "${readlink_output} " /proc/mounts > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

---

### Full working script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

translate_uuid_to_device_name()
{
    # Linux-specific; needs *BSD revision
    readlink -f -n /dev/disk/by-uuid/"${1}"
}

is_uuid_mounted()
{
    device_name=$( translate_uuid_to_device_name "${1}" )

    if [ -n "${device_name}" ]
    then
        # 1. basic regex should be working across platfotms
        #    tested on FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD with success
        #    I prefer the starting with (^) rather than filtering throung all text
        # 2. /proc/mounts is not available on all *BSDs, needs revision
        proc_mounts=$( grep "^${device_name} " /proc/mounts )
        [ -n "${proc_mounts}" ]
    fi
}

# Simplest Usage Example
if is_uuid_mounted "PUT_SOME_UUID_IN_HERE"
then
    echo "This UUID is mounted."
else
    echo "This UUID isn't mounted."
fi
```

---

Feel free to address further issues in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If findmnt is available, you can try :

```
test "$(findmnt -S UUID=$UUID)" || echo $UUID not mounted
```